# What has replaced the VERSIONINFO resource for C# projects?

Tags: c#, resx, rc, versioninfo

C# projects use a .resx file for resources. This is fine for strings, but it does not seem to have the equivilant of the old VERSIONINFO resource that the C++ project .rc files supported.

I can not believe that Microsoft has given up the idea of keeping track of executable versions ... so is there some VERSIONINFO-equivilent resource used with the .resx resource file?  How do you bind version information into a C# project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you select a project in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, right-click **Project/Properties**, and click the **Assembly Information** button, you can put your version information in the dialog box that opens.

The version information is stored in the resulting assembly's [manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w45z383.aspx).

Comment: Thank you.  I also found out there that you can bind in a .res file.  Oddly enough you can't add a .rc file to the project to have VS produce the .res file automatically.  But you can use them if you can produce them.